# Removing bold tags <b></b> on item click of a list javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple HTML form and a `div` under it (as a searchbox and autocomplete list).

I am dynamically adding a `<ul>` list to the "result" `div`. When I click on a list item, I am putting that value into the input box.

The problem is, when the item in the list is bolded, the text in the input box has the `<b></b>` tags around the bolded portion.

```html
<form>
    Search:
    <input type="text" id="searchbar">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
var search = document.getElementById("searchbar");
search.value= "ap";

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
    "<ul><li><b>ap</b>ple</li><li><b>ap</b>plication</li></ul>";

$('#result').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
    search.value = this.innerHTML;
});
```

You can see what I mean here: http://jsfiddle.net/avfyvk2v/41/

Is there a way I can remove the  tags in the searchbox? Thanks

Comment: The answer @Oriol has provided will work but you are mixing your presentational and data logic. I would recommend using the HTML5 data attribute on each li element instead like `<li data-value="application"><b>app</b>lication</li>` then filling the value of the text field with the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) instead of [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML):

```
search.value = this.textContent;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/avfyvk2v/42/)

Comment: What about: `search.value = $(this).text();`